# How to add a new text dynamically in between a multiline text of a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UILabel inside a UITableview cell. The label has multiline text. I need to add another label(text) in any one of the line(depending on some conditions) of the first label. Is it possible or is there an alternate way to do this?

Comment: Seems like it would be better to use multiple UILabels for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you have the lines break by newline characters or do you have one long line of text and ios does the breaking for you?

Comment: Lines broken by newline characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood: you want to edit your label to add some text.

Here's kinda sloppy way, but you can do something like that:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfLines = [labelOfYourCell.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

and then just add the desired text where you want and after that combine there strings in the array into 1 string, something like that:

```
NSString *finalString;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.count; i++) {
  finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", finalString, [arrayOfLines objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

that's just quick example without using Xcode, so there may be some errors.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Reload the cell of table view when you get required text

reload the row by using following method of "UITableView"

```
    – reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

and in "cellForRowAtIndexPat:(IndexPath*)indexPath" method create a new text and set in label